# rvm determine and install latest version of ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

So far I only know how to do commands like

```
rvm 2.0.0
```

Fortunately Google tells me

> The current stable version is 2.0.0-p247.

But shouldn't I be able to use rvm to do that step for me?  I can't figure out how to just tell rvm to install the latest version of ruby, without manually specifying it.

Answer (score 42):

it is enough to:

```
rvm get stable
rvm use ruby --install --default
```

it will update rvm, check for latest ruby - install it if missing - and set as default

Comment: for me it didn't install the latest version... not sure how in works, may be it is installing latest version about which rvm aware...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to have rvm just install the latest version automatically, but here's three simple commands using just rvm:

```
rvm reload
rvm list known # This will show all the available versions, including the latest
rvm install <latest_version> # Replace <latest_version> with the latest shown by the last command
```

Answer (score 4):

`rvm install ruby-head` should install the last known version.

Comment: this actually installs latest from ruby source, not the latest official ruby release