# Rails looking for wrong path of bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, path, bundler

I'm trying to create a new Ruby-on-Rails application with a fresh installation on Linux. When I execute

```
rails new appname -d postgresql
```

I receive the following error

```
         run  bundle install --local
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

But `bundle` is installed in a different path:

```
$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Is it preferable to change the path of `bundle` or to specify to `rails` that it is in a different path? And what is the best way to do it (either changing the path or specifying it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/<version>/bin` to your `.bash_profile` and source it.

Then you can install gems for your user without sudo with `gem install bundler --install-dir ~/.gem`

Answer (score 1):

try `gem install bundler` before doing it

Comment: I did that but I have no permission so I used `sudo gem install bundler` instead which is probably the reason why I'm having problems

Comment: I guess you should take a look to grant the permission... I believe you should do it without the sudo command... good luck bro

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I did was:

1. [Quick rvm install](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)
2. [Intalling the latest version of Ruby with rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599229/rvm-determine-and-install-latest-version-of-ruby)
3. `gem install bundler`